# Coordinate System of Flame Fractals

Tags: math, fractals

I have been doing some research on flame fractals in preparation of creating my own flame fractal generator. I just have one question: What coordinate system is used in the flame fractal algorithm?

Is it like the Mandelbrot Set with complex numbers, or is it a real number system?
Additionally, what is an optimal range to graph the flame fractals within (i.e. Mandelbrot uses (x-> -2 to 2),(y-> -2i to 2i))?

[Original Article about flame fractals](http://flam3.com/flame.pdf) (22Mb PDF)

Comment: Why don't you try mathoverflow.com?

Comment: You mean mathoverflow.net -- but math.stackexchange.com is better suited. The former is for research level questions, the latter for more basic questions.

Comment: math.stackexchange.com it is then :)

Comment: According to the article, it's R^2. And the optimal range depends on which fractal you choose. Are you asking something more?

Comment: I guess that answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinate system in Apophysis, flam3, and other implementations use (x,y), or (x,y,z). 
if it has 3d hack. However, some variations interpret (x,y) as if it was a complex number, for example, the mobius variation, or the julia variation.

The exact details on how the math is done is hard to understand, nobody really knows, 
since the existing code is very old, and has been developed by many people.
I have, for example, experienced some problems related to the y coordinate behaving strangely.

EDIT: Ah, Apophysis and flam3 uses sort of a camera function, which has a center point, rotation, and magnification. The center point is what will be mapped to the middle of the screen, and the rest, you'll be able to figure out.

I am actually coding on a Java implementation, which can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/flamethyst/home/Home/ 
Browse the code for details on camera, coordinates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, I believe that an error in the source code caused the y coordinate to flipped in one of the transforms so that the negative y axis extends upward and the positive y axis extends downward.

To answer your actual question about where to find information about the aweful mess that is the apophysis codebase, the secret place on the internet where most of the experts in how apophysis actually works is a deviantart chatroom at chat.deviantart.com/chat/aposhack. It requires that you sign up for a deviantart account.  In the chat, there are several people labeled 'wizards' who either work with the source code, have gotten sick of the source code and are writing their own flame generators, or are Thomas Ludwig, creator of [Chaotica](http://chaoticafractals.com/), which is a fractal flame renderer that does not have many of the bugs and mathematical issues as apophysis.

If you are still working on a flame generator, I invite you to stop by and talk fractals with us.